# Is it okay to use お願いします when asking your teacher for help?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, expressions

When asking a teacher for help, is it okay to use お願いします?

For example, asking to check my homework:

> 宿題をチェックしてお願いします。

To me, "Please check my homework." sounds kind of rude.

Would saying

> 宿題をチェックしてお願いできますか? (Would it be possible for you to check my homework?)

be any better ?

Answer (score 4):

When you ask somebody senior to you for a favor, you’d better add his / her ”honorable” title, e.g. 先生、先輩、師匠、部長、女将さん、親方 before asking.

And if he or she is your teacher, I would say “先生、宿題をチェックして頂けますか？“ or
“先生、宿題のチェックをお願いできますか？“ However the latter sounds somewhat redundant to me.

“チェックしてお願いできますか？” is just like saying “Would you kindly check (my homework) and may I ask?”, and is awkward in Japanese.

Answer (score 3):

These would be more natural:

> 宿題のチェックをお願いできますか？

noun(チェック) + を + お願いできますか？

> 宿題をチェックしていただけますか？

verb(して) + いただけますか？