# Asking for autograph politely

Tags: politeness, english-to-japanese

I am a big fan of badminton, especially the Japanese players like Kento Momota-san, and in a few months they will come to my country, and I would like to get some of them to sign their autograph in my autograph book. I was thinking of saying: "サインをください" or "サインをおねがいしますか？", would that be wrong to ask like that or is there a better polite way of asking?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48450/9831 and maybe https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38905/9831

Answer (score 2):

Taking your suggestions in turn: 「サインをください。」 sounds a bit demanding; it would be understood, but you can be more polite.

「サインをお願いしますか。」 is not natural, as お願いします is referring to your own wish; the か at the end rather thus confuses the nature of your wish.

I would probably go with: 
「サインをいただけますか。」 -- literally meaning: "Could I get/receive your autograph?". This is polite, but probably not overly so for the context you describe.

Comment: ah okay thank you for your comment! ありがとう！. i saw this video: https://youtu.be/s9QNE3p_taw but he just says "サインおねがいします" im thinking of saying that the first time i ask a player, and if they get mad/confused i will say "サインをいただけますか". thank you so much for the help, ありがとうございます！！

Answer (score 2):

サインをください isn’t used so much. サインください is better. And both are used more often by a delivery person.

I write here some examples you can use when you want his autograph.

サイン(を)頂くことって可能ですか？
サイン(を/って)頂いてもよろしいですか？
サイン(を)して頂いてもいいですか？
サイン(を)頂けませんか？
サイン(って)頂けますか？
サイン(を/って)貰うことってできますか？
サイン(って)して貰っても大丈夫ですか？
サイン(って)して貰ってもいいですか？
サイン(って)貰えますか？
サイン(って)大丈夫ですか？
サインいいですか？
サインお願いします。
サインください。

The higher is the more polite.